# Apache Configuration for ELB Health Check

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, webserver, amazon-elb

My website is hosted on AWS and currently it has a ELB health check URL is set to a static webpage(ping.php).

I want to set my health check URL to another page which is dynamic - with database connectivity. Also those web pages are authenticated with basic authentication as well.

My requirement is to have a path set in my AWS ELB which calls for the dynamic and authenticated web page and return the 200 response back to ELB.

How can I manage that in Apache configuration ?

Hope it's clear!

Thanks.

Comment: ALB is not going to authenticate to your website. You either have to make the url which does not require authentication or set a response code to whatever your authentication returns when rejecting the connections without authentication.

Comment: No problem. Did it work out? If yes, I can make an answer with some extra info?

Comment: I went with the non authenticated ping page and had a DB connection string there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that **ALB does not support** any type of authentication to your application, e.g. basic authentication. Therefore, ALB can't login to your app and perform health checks afterwards.

To overcome the issue, there are **two general solutions**:

1. Setup [health check HTTP code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html) to the code representing failure of authentication.
2. Modify your application to have normal health check endpoint without any authentication.